# Why does Chrome behave differently when transitioning media queries and floated elements?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Viewing this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QS5Gg/) in Chrome, when you increase the width of the result pane to be greater than 768px then drag it to reduce it, then bring it back, the menu on the left is (Home, Page2) is rendered in the element below it. However, if the page is rendered (i.e. you press "Run") with the result pane >= 768px, the menu is correctly floated to the right.

Is this a bug? Can it be avoided?

Here's the full code of the fiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #nav {

    }

    #nav ul {
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }

    #nav ul li {
      padding: 0 10px;
    }

    #content {
      background-color: #ccc;
      height: 200px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {  
      #nav ul {
        float: right;
      }

      #nav ul li {
        float: left;
      }  
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">  
      <a href="/">
        Logo Goes Here
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="news.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="people.html">Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because Chrome is buggy when it comes to redrawing at media query breakpoints.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I ended up forcing the redraw on resize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
  if(is_chrome) {
    $(window).resize(function(){
      // .show(0) is required for Chrome
      $('#nav ul').hide().show(0);
    });
  }
});
```